# Delete an item in array which is stored in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Im display some data into table and for each row there is `Delete button`, when button clicked it should `Delete` item in array which is stored in localStorage by passing id and than Assign it back to LocalStorage. 
HTML:

```
<table>
     <tbody id="ResultProduct">
       <tr class="RMAJS">
          <td><input type="text" id="item1" name="itemName" value="Computer" /></td>
          <td><a data-localstorage-id='ae90ac1a-64c4-49a7-b588-ae6b69a37d47' class="deletebtn">Delete</a></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="RMAJS">
         <td><input type="text" id="item2" name="itemName" value="Mobile" /></td>
         <td><a data-localstorage-id='6b1ccc7e-322c-4f5f-81f9-b1fd68c0eb8b' class="deletebtn">Delete</a></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

LocalStorage :

```
["ae90ac1a-64c4-49a7-b588-ae6b69a37d47","6b1ccc7e-322c-4f5f-81f9-b1fd68c0eb8b"]

0: "ae90ac1a-64c4-49a7-b588-ae6b69a37d47"
1: "6b1ccc7e-322c-4f5f-81f9-b1fd68c0eb8b"
```

JavaScript :

```
$('#ResultProduct').on('click', '.deletebtn', function (e) {
    var targetElement = $(e.target);
    var getID = $(targetElement).attr("data-localstorage-id");
    var getLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));

    for (var i = 0; i < getLocalStorage.length; i++) {
        var Val = getLocalStorage[i]

        //Here is my problem for example i want to delete this item 
       //"6b1ccc7e-322c-4f5f-81f9-b1fd68c0eb8b" from array 
       //How can i do that ??

       localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(??)); //Assign it back to LocalStorage.
    }

    $(targetElement).closest("tr.RMAJS").remove();
})
```

Comment: you can splice() it to remove an index entirely

Comment: `getLocalStorage = getLocalStorage.filter(item => item !== getID)`?

Comment: @dandavis so it will be like this :  Val.slice(getID, 1); ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#ResultProduct').on('click', '.deletebtn', function (e) {
    var targetElement = $(e.target);
    var getID = $(targetElement).attr("data-localstorage-id");

    var getLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
    getLocalStorage = getLocalStorage.filter(e => e !== getID);
    localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(getLocalStorage));

    $(targetElement).closest("tr.RMAJS").remove();
});
```